# How to add views in an existing view made in Interface Builder with Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout

I have a created the following auto layout in Interface Builder:

[image]

As you can see I didn't give any fix size to the buttons. I would like to add two button programmatically to get to this result:

[image]

Adding the constraints programmatically I know how to do that, at least I know the syntax.

My problem is when to create those buttons?

I create the width constraint based on the width of the button 4. If I do it in viewDidLoad (if I'm not wrong), the auto layout hasn't been set yet so the width (and height) will be wrong.

I thought to do it in viewDidLayoutSubviews but as it's called multiple times when loading the viewController, I get multiple buttons stacked on each other and when I go to landscape more buttons are added..

When should I create those button to have the right sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto layout is about rules that hold at all times, not (primarily) about frame sizes at any one moment.

You should not care about getting the frame of button 4 when you set up the constraints for buttons 5 and 6. The constraint that you add for buttons 5 and 6 should refer to button 4's width attribute, not its current width in points. That is, you could create a constraint like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint* constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button5 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:button4 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:0];
constraint.active = YES; // OR: [button5.superview addConstraint:constraint]
```

That's a constraint that will keep button 5's width the same as button 4's width, even as button 4's width changes. You would do the same for height, and for button 6. Etc.

Put another way, the constraints you create at runtime should be similar to those you would create in IB if you were doing this at design time. It doesn't look to me like you've created explicit, fixed height and width constraints on button 4. You've created relative constraints relating its height and width to other views.

One thing you will have to do: since buttons 2 and 4 have trailing space constraints to the container (or its margins), you will need to remove those constraints when you add buttons 5 and 6. Buttons 2 and 4 would have to have trailing constraints to buttons 5 and 6, respectively, and buttons 5 and 6 would have to have trailing constraints to the container. Actually, you should simplify by getting rid of button 4's trailing constraint to the container and replacing it with a trailing alignment constraint to button 2. Likewise, button 6's trailing edge should be aligned with button 5's, not spaced from the superview's. That way, you only have to remove one constraint (button 2's trailing to superview) and add one (button 5's trailing to superview).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was actually using `let button_constraint_H:Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[container500(width)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metricsDictionary, views: viewsDictionary)` where `width` was coming from `button.bounds.width`. So using `constraintsWithVisualFormat` is not possible in my case? About removing constraints, how can I remove one particular constraint that I created in IB as there is no id for constraint (or tag)? Do I have to remove them all and then create just the needed ones (not really practical then). Thanks again

Comment: You can use the visual format language if you pass button 4 in as one of the views: `H:[button5(==button4)]`. To remove a constraint, you can create an outlet to it and connect it in IB, just like any other outlet. For instance, open the Assistant editor to show your controller class and Control-drag from the constraint in IB to your controller class and create the outlet.

Comment: Didn't realised you could make an outlet with a constraint. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can create the constraints programmatically in `viewDidLoad`. If you made an `IBOutlet` for the buttons, then you can access them and get the size like so:

```
self.myButton.frame.size.height;
```

You can use the [Autolayout Constraints](http://autolayoutconstraints.com/) tool, to make this process easier.

Comment: I actually get a wrong size when I do it in viewDidLoad while I get the right size from viewDidLayoutSubviews. Thanks for the link though